# Which Schengen countries (don't) stamp passports of ordinary residence permit holders?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, paperwork, passport-stamps

The Schengen Borders Code doesn't prescribe an exception from stamping travel documents for holders of ordinary residence permits (as opposed to family member "Article 10"/"Article 20" residence cards).

However, in truth practice varies between member states.

So which countries stamp ordinary residence permit holders, and which ones don't?

Comment: I'm curious. What purpose will this serve?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Many people ask about a lack of stamps on here, so this will be a handy reference for Schengen residence permit holders

Comment: "doesn't prescribe an exception": I would state it more plainly.  The code prescribes a general requirement that their documents be stamped in Article 11(1), but the list of particular cases does not include third-country nationals with residence permits.  As far as I understand it, this means that residence permit holders are included in the requirement, but perhaps I do not understand the technical operation of "in particular."  I've asked a question over at [Law.SE]: [What does “in particular” mean in EU legislation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/52459/333)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is based on emails from the relevant authorities (*to be continuously updated*):

**Countries that stamp**:

- Austria
- Belgium
- Czech Republic
- Denmark
- France
- Hungary
- Italy
- Latvia
- Lithuania
- Malta
- Netherlands
- Norway
- Portugal

**Countries that don't stamp**:

- Finland
- Estonia
- Germany
- Iceland
- Poland
- Slovakia
- Slovenia
- Sweden
- Switzerland

Comment: Do any of the countries stamp passports of residents only if the residence permit was issued by another country (for example, Spain stamping passports of residence permit holders of other Schengen countries but not those of holders of Spanish residence permits)?

Comment: @phoog Never thought to ask, but none of the authorities so far have mentioned such a thing (I just asked about Schengen residence permits in general)

Comment: For information, Germany (at least at FRA) did not stamp my passport with a Swiss permit; Italy (at LIN) did.

Comment: Recent data point: Portugal (at LIS, with Sweden permit) did put a stamp.

Comment: What about Spain?