# Passport Stamping and Residents cards

Tags: schengen, transit, passport-stamps

I am a U.K. citizen with a Bulgarian residents card. If I fly into Spain, does my passport have to be stamped as a third country national now after Brexit. Also if I transit Spain or another Member state on route to BG does it also get stamped?

Comment: May be relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157743/which-schengen-countries-dont-stamp-passports-of-ordinary-residence-permit-ho

Comment: Your residence in a non-Schengen country as no effect on the entry or exit of the Schengen Area. Your passport should allways be stamped on entry and exit. Should, for whatever reason, this be 'forgotten' **retain** some proof of when you entered or left as proof that you did not overstay. Until the **Entry/Exit System (EES)** is introduced, the entry/exit stamps will remain a requirement.

Comment: @MarkJohnson This might be wrong: British citizens residing in the EU/Schengen on WA terms are NOT to be stamped at least by the country of residence. As for other EU/Schengen states, I'm unsure

Comment: @Crazydre [Schengen Border Code - Article 11(3)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399#d1e1477-1-1) **No entry or exit stamp shall be affixed:** (g) states **who present a residence card provided for in Directive 2004/38/EC.**, which applies to *members of the family of a Union citizen*. Other exceptions for 3rd country nationals, who are residents, are not listed in this article.

Comment: It could be argued that British citizens who reside in the EU still enjoy (some) freedom of movement rights (which would exempt them from most of the Schengen Borders Code rules). The withdrawal agreement isn't explicit about that. It's not relevant for British citizens but EU citizens who reside in the UK can use their national ID card until 2025 (vs. September 2021 for those who don't) so clearly the UK isn't free to impose a stamping requirement until then. Why would the EU be? Pointing to the general Schengen rules does nothing to clarify this issue.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The Borders Code is hardly a foolproof reference. Even with completely ordinary residence permits, stamping is regulated at the national level with many states not doing it.

Comment: @Relaxed Right you are; for me as a Swedish national having moved to the UK in December 2020, in effect, **Brexit never happened**, so long as I spend 50% of my time in the UK for the next 5 years (with evidence of 1 day's physical presence counting for a whole month). It's largely the same the other way round, hence, for example, Schengen states must accept the Gibraltar ID for those residing in that specific state on WA terms (with many also accepting it for those residing in other Schengen states on WA terms)

Comment: @Crazydre The question is what happens in October when the passport requirement starts. The UK may start issuing a 'leave to enter' stamp (at least for for visitors).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Nope, confirmed it won't happen. Nor do they stamp AU/CA/JP/NZ/US passports. The exception is if entering in TIer 5 or Permitted Paid Engagement status, in which case you get stamped (on a form IS116 if using an ID card)

Answer (score -4):

Yes, your passport should be stamped when entering or leaving the Schengen Area.

The [Schengen Border Code - Article 11](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399#d1e1477-1-1) states that all 3rd country nationals should be systematically stamped.

Article 11(3) gives a list of exceptions:

- (g):  **who present a residence card provided for in Directive 2004/38/EC.**

  - which applies to *members of the family of a Union citizen*

Other exceptions for 3rd country nationals, who are residents, are not listed in this article.

---

British citizens will receive a **residence permit** based on the  *Withdrawal Agreement Article 18(4)*.

[image]

Any previous issued **residence card** must be replaced with this document and became invalid after the 31st of December 2020 (and with it the Freedom of Movement).

> **Do I continue to have the possibility to move freely within the European Union?**
> No, this possibility **ceased to exist** when the United Kingdom withdrew from the European Union – unless you fulfil the conditions under the Withdrawal Agreement in a number of countries, in which case you can also assert your right in these other countries. Please note that the procedures and deadlines may be different in other Member States. In addition, of course, if you are also a citizen of another EU or EEA state, you can continue to assert your mobility rights.
>
> A further, limited possibility for mobility within the EU exists if you fulfil the conditions for a permanent EU residence permit or for the EU Blue Card. You can apply for these rights of residence for third-country nationals even if you have an entitlement under the Withdrawal Agreement.
>
> In combination with your passport, your **new residence document** enables you *to travel within the Schengen countries for up to 90 days within a 180-day period. However, **it does not allow** you to work in or move to other countries*. To do that, you require permission from the other country concerned.
>
> Your residence document does not constitute any form of entitlement outside the Schengen countries. That also applies to the EU member states that are not Schengen states, i.e. Bulgaria, Croatia, Romania and Cyprus. Ireland has special rules for UK nationals.

---

**Sources**:

- [Schengen Border Code - Article 11](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399#d1e1477-1-1)
- [BMI - Constitution - Information for UK nationals and their family members about the right of residence provided for in the Withdrawal Agreement](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/constitution/brexit/faqs-brexit.html#doc15091950bodyText4)

Comment: Firstly, far from all Schengen states stamp residence permit holders in general (it's decided at the national level - *ihr tut es z.B. nicht!*). Secondly the Withdrawal Agreement has an impact; if OP were residing in Spain, they definitely aren't to be stamped by Spain, but with residents of other EU/Schengen states I'm unsure (the EC didn't give me a clear reply, which is of course poor on their part)

Comment: @Crazydre Since the Schengen Border code states *systematically*, one should assume that it will be. That is the question the OP is asking. So the answer is: yes, it should be stamped.

Comment: I'm telling you the Borders Code doesn't necessarily correspond to national policy, which differs between member states. It's because of an EC recommendation, just above chapter 4 here https://ec.europa.eu/transparency/regdoc/rep/1/2009/EN/1-2009-489-EN-F1-1.Pdf. And again, the WA comes into play as well

Comment: @Crazydre The point before chapter 4 deals with *residence permit issued by a **Schengen Member State***, which is not the case for Bulgaria where the OP lives.

Comment: There is a question on here somewhere, or maybe on [Expatriates.SE] in which @Crazydre makes it abundantly clear through some very convincing evidence that some Schengen countries do not stamp passports of residence permit holders even though the SBC quite clearly says that they should.  Before hanging your position too securely on the letter of the SBC, you may want to seek out that question. While Bulgaria isn't yet fully in the Schengen area, it does implement some of the Schengen acquis, so practice may be similar for holders of Bulgarian permits.

Comment: @phoog The reason why many states don't stamp is the EC recommendation which I linked. I know most states' policies through having emailed them (still haven't managed to get a reply from Czechia, Greece, Luxembourg and Spain). Haven't checked BG+CY+HR+RO at all yet.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Much of Schengen regulations also covers BG+CY+HR+RO. That said, I haven't actually checked those countries' policies, hence saying the answer isn't obvious unless you have it from the Bulgarians.

Comment: @Crazydre That EC recommendation applies to residents of Schengen member states. Page 7 of pdf: *Questioning of the necessity of stamping the travel documents of third-country nationals who are in possession of a valid residence permit issued by a Schengen Member State.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson Doesn't prevent the others from using it as a basis for their national practice too. The point is it's *de facto* decided at the national level, with the EC not interfering in any of it

Comment: Does it make a difference that I am the partner of a Swiss national, as we are not married “but in a long term durable relationship attested” as the eu puts it. As can provide proof of living together . As if we are married.

Comment: @Tim If you have an Article 10 **residence card** and have it with you when entering or leaving, then the exception Article 11(3)(g) applies.