# Does Germany stamp my passport upon exit?

Tags: passport-stamps

I'm wondering if I fly to Frankfurt Main from Spain and stay overnight in a hotel outside the airport and then fly out of the EU the next day, does my passport get stamped?
I have residency in Spain but not a EU citizenship.
I already know that if I don't exit the airport after my flight from Spain and just go directly to my overseas flight, passport does NOT get stamped.
However, now I'm not sure if the same things happens if I stay overnight in Frankfurt (meaning I exit the airport and come back the next day).

follow-up question: does this apply to every city in Germany that has an international airport, or just FRA?

Comment: What's your status in Spain? In general, Germany *should* stamp your passport.

Comment: Hi I have non-lucrative residency in Spain (six month minimum stay per yr, no work permit).

Comment: In principle you should get stamps then. You never got one since you have that permit? Anywhere (Spain, Germany, or any other Schengen country)?

Comment: @Relaxed as has been discussed elsewhere on this site, many Schengen countries refrain from stamping passports of those with residence permits.  I suppose Germany is one.  Regardless, Germany's practice, whatever it is, probably does not depend on whether the traveler leaves the airport before leaving the Schengen area, nor on which checkpoint the traveler uses.  See https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157743/19400, where Germany is indeed in the "don't stamp" list.

Answer (score 5):

On the first day, your flight from Spain should land in the Schengen area of the terminal and you should simply walk out of the airport without any passport check. That ought to be true in any Schengen airport, in Germany and elsewhere. If for some reason (unusual airport layout or operational issues) you do end up in a non-Schengen terminal, you might have to cross a check point but still shouldn't get a stamp (it has happened to me a couple of times on departure).

You would then go through passport control when leaving the Schengen area. Leaving the airport or how long you spend in Frankfurt shouldn't play a role at all and you should be treated the same whether you come straight from a Schengen flight or from outside the airport.

Whether that means you will get a stamp depends on the type of residence permit you have and how thorough border guards are. Most third country nationals residing in the EU *should* get stamps but some don't (e.g. family members of EU citizens) and some countries do not apply that rule consistently or even [systematically omit to stamp passports for all residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157743/which-schengen-countries-dont-stamp-passports-of-ordinary-residence-permit-ho). If you know for a fact that you wouldn't get a stamp if you did not leave the airport then it should be the same when coming from your hotel.

Comment: I’d note that back when I was a permanent resident of the EU stamping was also 50/50. Seemed to depend on the border guards mood.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for the thorough response. This issue has always been confusing to me. So Germany is NOT like the US. It does stamp passports upon exit but it doesn't if you're a resident in a EU country. Do I understand it correctly?  Is all of Germany like this? I would assume so but for some reason Frankfurt was recommended to me.

Comment: @polaatx No, that's not quite correct. They *should* stamp passports on entry AND on exit, even residents. People who do not get stamps are EU citizens, their family, and a handful or others (diplomats, airline crew…) If you didn't get a stamp, it's because they made a mistake or couldn't be bothered (which, as Jonathan noted, is common and doesn't matter much in your situation but is still a mistake). Is there a reason you don't want a stamp?

Comment: See [Which Schengen countries (don't) stamp passports of ordinary residence permit holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157743/19400)

Comment: @Relaxed my Spanish residency requires me to stay in the country a minimum of 6 months a year. But a job assignment is keeping me abroad longer. Once before I exited via Frankfurt and I didn't get a stamp. I learned it from other residents who use the same tactic to avoid the stamp so when they apply to renew their residency their passport does not show exits from EU. They say they don't get stamped entering / existing EU via Germany.  I'm sure there are digital records, but I guess the Spanish are not checking it.  Is this news to you? That's why I was asking what is different about Germany.

Comment: It's not news to me that stamping is haphazard, I am not really following the detail beyond that and I didn't realise Germany never ever stamped passports for residents. They are still supposed to do it that why I think it's not quite correct to compare it to the US, that's what I meant. Now if the goal is avoiding stamps, that's a different question, you might find the link provided by @phoog more useful for that purpose.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid being documented as out of the country then you should seriously rethink this as your financial records will show that you are out of the country, and you will 
presumably need to make criminally false declarations of residency to the tax office.

Comment: @Relaxed Germany doesn't stamp residence permit holders, period. It's based on an EC recommendation, causing many Schengen states to adopt this practice

Comment: @Crazydre Yes, phoog pointed me to the question discussing that issue. I edited that in and mentioned it in my last comment. The regulation still says they should and that's binding for the commission too.

Comment: @Relaxed To clarify, not stamping is based on this https://ec.europa.eu/transparency/documents-register/detail?ref=COM(2009)489&lang=en ("page 6" - actually the 7th page of the PDF)

Comment: @Crazydre It wasn't particularly unclear or relevant to my answer. As I said, the regulation is binding on the commission, even an actual recomendation would be questionable and a report cannot be the basis for anything. It doesn't even pretends to, it concludes that ”The Commission underlines that travel documents of third-country nationals who are in possession of a valid residence permit of a Schengen Member State are exempted from the stamping obligation on entry and exit” as if it had self-evidently been the case all along.

Comment: @Relaxed "and a report cannot be the basis for anything" Well it is in many member states, that's the simple fact, whether academically legal or not

Comment: @Crazydre Not really, the simple fact is that they are just doing it in spite of what the regulation prescribes. The report reflects that, with some contradictions and contortions. That's quite common and already covered in my answer (and your own helpful Q&A on the topic). Whether they have a basis for it is not a question of fact, it's inherently a theoretical legal question but I don't think it's all that useful to debate it detail.