# Gibraltar to Spain border passport stamping

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, spain, gibraltar

I am a US citizen with Spanish residency. I have been living in Gibraltar for two months but I heard they start stamping passports now for non Gibraltar residents and I never received an entry stamp entering Gibraltar. Does anyone know if Spain is stamping passport as of now?

Comment: Does it matter?  A Spanish stamp in your passport has no effect on your right to stay in Spain.

Comment: @phoog If the OP is outside of Spain longer than 6 months, that may effect their residence status. [How Long Can I Be Outside Spain Without Losing my Residency?](https://www.immigrationspain.es/en/maximum-time-outside-spain-without-losing-residency/)

Comment: @phoog My main concern is that I don’t have an exit stamp, so I’m not sure if it will affect my renewal since they can’t determine my time outside of Spain

Comment: De facto Gibraltar is now part of the Schengen area. Spanish border police check (and stamp) passports at the Gibraltar airport, but no longer at the border between Spain and Gibraltar.

Comment: @KristvanBesien That was the original plan (to become effected on the 1st of July), but: [2021-07-20: UK clashes with EU over Gibraltar's post-Brexit status - BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-57908376), so it would seem that things have stalled...

Comment: You ought to be able to use other evidence to establish your presence in Spain.  Do you have any receipts showing that you were in Spain the day before you went to Gibraltar?  Transportation tickets or fuel receipts from the trip to Gibraltar?  There are so many Schengen countries that would not stamp your passport on entry or exit (see [Which Schengen countries (don't) stamp passports of ordinary residence permit holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157743/19400)) that Spain must be well experienced in judging the duration of someone's absence without using passport stamps.