# Does my passport need to be stamped while re-entering Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, passport-stamps, long-stay-visas

I applied for residence permit after entering the country on a D visa. Residence card is not yet issued. I left the Schengen area (with an exit stamp). And soon I am returning while my D visa is still valid. I predict my card is not issued yet still.

At the border, should my passport be stamped? I heard someone saying it shouldn't, which is really confusing

> just give the proof of residency (he is referring to the paper given to me when I applied for the permit) along with your passport and ask them not to stamp you

What's his logic?

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What would be the use of asking for your passport not to be stamped?

Comment: No idea. Maybe he knows some rule such as once you are a resident of a EU country, your passport shouldn't get stamped while entering EU?

Comment: @oooooo If you're asking about some single random unknown person's advice, perhaps you should cite that advice, or at least put it in context?

Comment: Your passport should be stamped if you return to the Schengen zone from outside it. I don't think you can decide whether to get a stamp or not, most times you only answer if asked about anything. Otherwise, it goes "Hi, officer checks and stamps, hands back passport"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What am I supposed to do?

Stop worrying.  Since you have a valid D visa and a residence permit on the way, it doesn't much matter whether your passport is stamped.  No harm will come from having a stamp, nor will any harm come from lacking a stamp.

The Schengen Borders Code actually calls for your passport to be stamped even *after* your residence permit is issued, but many countries have noticed that there's not much point in that practice so they've officially abandoned it.  [Some do; some don't.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157743/19400)  It just doesn't matter much.

> What am I supposed to do?

Give your documents to the passport inspector and see what happens.

Comment: That's a brilliant answer. The residence permit will play the role of visa for you in the future, but stamping of the passport will continue for you.  Imagine if you tear off a page with a visa from your passport and try to enter the Schengen zone. This will be the same case if you enter the Schengen zone with a residence permit only. This will not work, your passport *plus* permit will work together on the border and surely your passport will be stamped.

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu "surely your passport will be stamped.": as this answer mentions, this is not always the case.

Comment: @GoodDeeds thank you for pointing and correcting me.

Comment: If you tear a page off your passport, chances are the passport is not valid anymore and you will have problems bigger than the stamp.