# Does Spain stamp passports of Schengen residence permit holders while entering/exiting Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, spain

I looked into here [Which Schengen countries (don't) stamp passports of ordinary residence permit holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157743/which-schengen-countries-dont-stamp-passports-of-ordinary-residence-permit-ho) but couldn't see anything about Spain

Comment: Anecdotally, I have a residence permit from a different Schengen state, and they didn't stamp my passport at Madrid airport when I flew to London Heathrow in December.

Comment: @djr I wonder if its safe to assume they also wouldn't stamp the passport when you enter Schengen from Spain

Comment: No idea. In December I travelled there from within Schengen. I also don't know whether they are consistent or not. Out of interest, why do you care?

Comment: I'm a bit weird

Answer (score 1):

Often flying through Madrid and my experience is that they nearly always stamp.