# Why do some Schengen countries not stamp passports of residence permit holders?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, passport-stamps, residency

You're a resident of Schengen country A.

You're entering or exiting Schengen via Schengen country B.

B doesn't stamp your passport while entering/exiting.

Why is that?

Doesn't this complicate things or cause problems in some Schengen countries for certain procedures?

Slightly relevant: [Which Schengen countries (don't) stamp passports of ordinary residence permit holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157743/which-schengen-countries-dont-stamp-passports-of-ordinary-residence-permit-ho)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146381/discussion-on-question-by-oooooo-why-do-some-schengen-countries-not-stamp-passpo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Presently, the passport stamps are used for the calculation of the duration of the authorised stay of third country nationals. (The *90 days in any 180-day period* rule)

Article 11 of the Schengen Border Code does **not** list **residence permit** card holders as being exempted from the passport stamp requirement.

Since the 90 day rule **does not** apply while in the country of residence, the passport stamps served no practical purpose as proof that the 3rd country national has overstayed while outside of their country of residence.

Since changes to the Schengen Border Code were planned for the introduction of the Entry/Exit System (EES), that would take this into account, no changes were made to the Border Code in 2017.

Some countries simply stopped stamping the passports of **residence permit** card holders in expectation of this change.

---

When the [Entry/Exit System (EES)](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/smart-borders/entry-exit-system_en) is introduced (now expected in 2024), the entry and exit recording will be done electronically and the passport stamps abolished.

Article 2 (3) of REGULATION (EU) 2017/2226 (Entry/Exit System (EES)) contains a list of persons who will be exempt from the recording of their entry and exit.

Among these are **residence permit** card holders and persons with a long-stay visas.

Comment: Thanks, "now expected in 2024" can you link a source? I couldn't fnd it

Comment: @oooooo No, there is none. An official statement doesn't exist to my knowlage. They want to get right before starting so that events, such as in Dover, don't happen. The nearest is this: [2023-01-24: New EU border checks delayed until the end of 2023. Why are airlines supportive?](https://www.euronews.com/travel/2023/01/18/new-eu-border-controls-delayed-until-end-of-2023-how-will-the-ees-affect-travellers)

Comment: Thanks, would they exchange historical data or would it be from 2024 and onwards?

Comment: @oooooo How can they? The stamps are in the passports of the travelers.

Comment: e.g Germany let you into Schengen area without stamping your passport. They keep those historical records. Why wouldn't they exchange that historical data with other Schengen countries as a part of that electronic system if/when it gets implemented?

Comment: @oooooo Your assumption that historical records exist is wrong. There is presently no legal basis for such a data collection.

Comment: How can Germany figure out if you overstayed if they don't have historical records?

Comment: @oooooo They look at the passport stamp or the residence permit card.

Comment: @oooooo they don't care whether you overstayed 10 years ago.  Under the assumptions of this question, the traveler has a residence permit from a Schengen country.  Overstay enforcement by other countries isn't a priority.  If a Schengen resident comes to the attention of the police in another Schengen country, they can investigate the person's whereabouts using other evidence and possibly send the person to the country of residence.  Otherwise, the resident may be able to get away with living in the wrong country until the residence permit expires.

Comment: @MarkJohnson But many Schengen countries don't stamp the passport while you're entering or exiting Schengen. So them looking at the physical passport stamp is useless. Overstaying was an example (albeit a bit weak). Countries want to identify who is who, if they entered the country before etc. That's why borders exist

Comment: @oooooo If someone has a valid residence permit, they don't care when they enter or leave the Schengen Area.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Oh ok so all schengen countries look you up using your schengen residence permit when you're entering/exiting Schengen and they add a record which is linked to your residence permit. That's the "stamp". All Schengen countries can see those records? e.g when its time for permit renewal, country you reside can see the "stamps" of Germany

Comment: @oooooo No, not presently (for the new system: yes). Presently they look at your residence permit card.

Comment: Presently, when you're entering Schengen from Germany (they don't stamp), they look at your card and passport... and then what? They put a "entry stamp" digitally which is linked to the residence permit, right? This database is only domestic or shared between schengen countries that don't stamp passports?

Comment: @oooooo Once they have determined that you can enter, then you enter **<period>**. Nothing more.

Comment: Please also take this conversation to the chatroom made for the question.