Border control stamps entering EU when holding EU residency
I hold German residency (because I am married to a German citizen). I am in Dublin, Ireland at the moment, and I'll return to Germany through France. Will my passport get stamped at the French border control?
The reason I am asking this question is because on direct flights Ireland - Germany I didn’t get my passport stamped.

I suppose your residence permit is not an Article 10 card (since you reside in the country your spouse is a national of), and in this case it varies by country, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157744/30703 which seems to say France will probably stamp your passport.
